# No me regresa un raise con ValueError

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
def sum_digits(s):

    r = ''.join(x for x in s if x.isdigit())
    newList = list(r)
    try:
        result = sum(int(i) for i in newList)
    except:
        raise ValueError
    return result


print(sum_digits("a;d"))
```

Se deben de *encontrar los números en una cadena*, y si no se encuentran me debe de regresar un **ValueError**, pero no me lo esta regresando, de echo **me regresa 0.**
Espero alguien pueda ayudarme. Muchas Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te pasa eso porque nunca va a haber un error en el `try` con esas condiciones. `newlist` va a ser una lista de caracteres numéricos (por lo que el casting a `int` siempre va a funcionar) o una lista vacía si no hay ninguno (en este caso `sum` retornará 0).

Si quieres que lanze un `ValueError` cuando no exista ningún carácter numérico usa un condicional para ver si la lista está vacía o no:

```
def sum_digits(s):

    aux = [int(i) for i in s if i.isdigit()]
    if not aux:
        raise ValueError
    return sum(aux)
```

Esta función suma los caracteres que son dígitos, no los cuenta:

> ```
> >>> print(sum_digits("1a;4d7"))
> 12
> >>> print(sum_digits("a;d"))
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\...", line 29, in <module>
>     print(sum_digits("a;d"))
>   File "D:\...", line 26, in sum_digits
>     raise ValueError
> ValueError
> ```

Comment: muchas gracias, no sé porque me quede con la idea del `try`

Answer (score 0):

Podrías intentar con la siguiente función eliminar el manejo de excepciones, ten en cuenta que en **newstring** nunca habra algo que no sea un numero, de esta manera con un map conviertes a lista de números y los sumas. Además controlas que si lo uses en procesos iterativos no te rompa el proceso e incluso controlar que devuelve en estos casos.

```
def sum_digits(string):
    newstring = ''.join(ch for ch in string if ch.isdigit())
    if len(newstring)==0:
        return None
    else:    
        return sum(map(int, newstring))

# véase
sum_digits("aszdas")
sum_digits("1aszdas,2")
Out[1]: 
3
```